# socket.io get socket's variable in namespace

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm using socket.io 1.7.2 and try to catch all users with variables I defined to them in namespace - room.

Here example:

```
io.of('/playspace')
    .on('connection', function (socket) {
        socket.join('lobby');
        socket.on('apply user data', function (userData) {
            //Defined data to this (user)
            socket.username = userData.username;
            socket.balance = 1000;
        }
    });
```

And I'm get users list with

```
console.log(io.nsps['/playspace'].adapter.rooms['lobby']);
```

**Question:**

1. How to retrieve user with variable I defined like...

   `console.log(io.nsps['/playspace'].adapter.rooms['lobby'][0].username);`
2. How to loop and fetch

(Here exmaple it's work but without namespace and room)

```
for (var clientId in io.sockets.clients().connected ) {
    this_client = io.sockets.connected[clientId];
    console.log(this_client.username);
}
```

But with namespace and room, I have no idea

Answer (score 1):

I found solution...

Answer:

1.

```
io.of('/playspace').sockets[socket.id].username
```

Waiting for 2